# vba vlookup keep formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, vlookup, vba

My code below has a vlookup which changes a cell in my data (CurrentMonth), but I can't get it to keep the formatting of the source. The return values in col 2 are 01, 02, 03 etc up to 12 in general text format, but the formula below returns 1, 2, 3 etc.

I've tried putting a ' before the numbers in the table I'm looking into, but that doesn't work. Also tried copying the format with code and then pastespecial formats on the changed value, but this doesn't work. The format type of the lookup table and the data I'm changing are identical. What code do I need to keep the formating please so I don't lose the 0 at the beginning, keeping the lookup value as text?

```
'vlookup based on combobox selection held in variable
    Cat3No = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.Value, (Worksheets("ValidCombos").Range("C:D")), 2, False)

'variable used to change cell in dataset
    Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Cells(Currentrow, 32).Value = Cat3No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the values to be text, you could format the cells as a Custom format of Type "00":

[image: Format Cells]

**EDIT**

A simpler answer is to change your code to this:

```
'vlookup based on combobox selection held in variable
    Cat3No = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBoxCat3Name.Value, (Worksheets("ValidCombos").Range("C:D")), 2, False)

'variable used to change cell in dataset
    With Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Cells(Currentrow, 32)
        .Value = Cat3No
        .NumberFormat = "00"
    End With
```

Comment: Many thanks! You've really helped me out the last couple of days!